# Intermittent exceptions in CopyRows_management

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

Occasionally, but frequently enough to be a pain, my script throws an error. The script runs fine most of the time but when it fails, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXX.py", line 493, in main
    arcpy.CopyRows_management(ABC, XYZ)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 13547, in CopyRows
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000224: Cannot insert features
Failed to execute (CopyRows).
```

where `ABC` is a feature class in SDE and `XYZ` is a feature class in the local scratch.gdb. The name of `XYZ` is derived from the date and time and, I believe, should never encounter an issue with locks at this stage of the script.

What can be causing this error and how do I fix it?

Update 2 - SDE is on the network. Data is copied from SDE to the local GDB and then processed. The results are sent back to SDE upon completion of various tasks.

Update 1 - The path to the `scratch.gdb` is created automatically by ArcMap and located in "`C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\scratch.gdb`". Feature class names are similar to "`z_JSdzG2G_xyz`" where "`z_`" is a constant and helps to push these FCs to the bottom of the list, "`JSdzG2G`" is an encoded date and timestamp, and "`_xyz`" is a 3 - 6 character description of what's contained in the FC.

Comment: What is the path and name of the destination GDB?  I've run into these types of problems with file and path names that have non text characters.

Comment: @dblanchett I updated the question with additional information.

Comment: SDE geodatabase is on your PC or on a network? Could be a network connectivity issue.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov, I updated the question with additional information.

Comment: Alright, so all the operations are run on the data stored within the file geodatabases on your machine. However, you say that `"where ABC is a feature class in SDE"`. So the ABC is a local file gdb fc, right? Another question, why do you run Copy Rows instead of Copy Features, is there any specific reason for that? I've never used Copy Rows for copying feature class data; I've used Copy Rows only for tables. From the Help of Copy Rows: "If the input rows are a feature class, then only the attributes, and not the geometry, are copied to the output table."

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov, I copy the data down from the network (SDE) to a local (on my machine) file geodatabase (ESRI's built-in scratch.gdb) for processing. I don't know why I'm using copy_rows vs copy_features. I probably found a code sample somewhere that used it so I implemented it. It worked and I moved on.

Comment: Do you understand that you don't get shapes copied with the Copy Rows? The Copy Rows will only copy the attributes, its output is Table, not a feature class. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000n4000000. Is it what you need? Then you should edit your question. /// PS. Try running the same code with Copy Features in a loop 1000 times and see if you get the error again.

Comment: I understand the difference between the two commands and copy_rows happens to meet my needs. Why would I change it? This script takes 5 minutes to run and last night it ran every 15 minutes and completed successfully dozens of times in a row: overall 90% of the runs were successful. I'll switch to copy_features since I have nothing else to try.

Comment: Is there a chance there is an automated process running that locks the files?  I ran into issues like that when certain files were automatically getting backed up on saves that the backup program got in between and caused issues.

Comment: @Branco, I watched the GDB folder in Windows Explorer - before, during, and after execution. There are no locks to start, locks are created during execution, and the locks are removed upon completion of the script. I'll add some code to check for any lock files before execution and log their presence. To answer your question, there should not be any automated processes creating locks and I haven't found evidence of any.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error message in your question which is [000224 and documented](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00vp0000000n000224).

I recommend that you try the solution suggested there, or if you already have then to include the results of that within your question:

> **Description**
>
> The tool failed to write records to the output feature class or table.
>   This error is typically the result of mismatched field definitions
>   between incoming features and the output feature class or table.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Where possible, adjust the input field properties to be consistent
>   with the expected output field properties.